# Background Service Capturing Geolocation Gets Killed Under Specific Scenarios in Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, background-process

I have developed a background service in my flutter app that captures the user's geolocation and stores it in SQLite. However, I've observed that the service gets terminated under certain conditions. I've listed these scenarios below:

**App Killed when Device Steady:** When I force stop the app and let the device remain stationary, the background service stops after about 3 minutes.

**App Killed when Screen Off:** If I terminate the app and then turn off the device screen, again the service is terminated after roughly 3 minutes.

**App Killed & Using Another App:** Interestingly, when I kill the app but engage with another application on the device, the background service runs uninterrupted for a long duration.

I'm trying to understand why the service gets killed in the first two scenarios, but not in the third. Is there something I'm missing with regards to how background services work under different conditions? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Code can be checked below:

Background service initialization method:

```
Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'my_foreground', // id
    'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE', // title
    description:
    'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high, // importance must be at low or higher level
  );

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_bg_service_small'),
      ),
    );
  }
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      // this will be executed when app is in foreground or background in separated isolate
      onStart: onStart,

      // auto start service
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,

      notificationChannelId: 'my_foreground',
      initialNotificationTitle: 'Background Service',
      initialNotificationContent: 'Initializing',
      foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(),
  );
  service.startService();
}
```

On Start Method

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();


  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await preferences.setString("backgroundStatus", "true");


  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });
    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }
  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 20), (timer) async {
    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      if (await service.isForegroundService()) {

 method.
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          888,
          'Live Location',
          'Tracking ${DateTime.now()}',
          const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'my_foreground',
              'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE',
              icon: 'ic_bg_service_small',
              ongoing: true,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    print('FLUTTER BACKGROUND SERVICE: ${DateTime.now()}');
    onLocationTrackingStart();
  });
}
```

Storing geolocation to SQLight Database

```
Future<void> onLocationTrackingStart() async {
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
  );
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100),() async {
    SQLHelper.insertNoteRaw(position.latitude, position.longitude, DateTime.now().toString());
    // await SQLHelper.insertLocation(geoLocation).whenComplete(() =>print(position.latitude.toString()));
    initializeService();
  });

}
```